# error: expected a type, got 'struct' c++

Tags: c++

I got a class:

```
template <typename T> 
class btree {

  public:
    btree(size_t maxNodeElems);
    ~btree() {}

    struct node {  
      list <T> elements;
      node *lvl;
    };

  private:
    size_t maxNodeElems;
    node*  root;   

};

template <typename T>
btree<T>::btree(size_t maxNodeElems) {
  if (maxNodeElems > 0) maxNodeElems = maxNodeElems;
  root = new node;
  root->lvl = new node[maxNodeElems+1];
}

template <typename T>
pair <typename btree<T>::iterator, bool> btree <T>::insert (const T& elem) {
  pair <btree<T>::node, bool> start;
  start = addElement (elem, *root);
  pair <typename btree<T>::iterator, bool> final;
  return final;
}

template <typename T>
pair <btree<T>::node, bool> btree<T>::addElement (const T& e, btree<T>::node*& n) {

  n->elements.push_back(e);
  return make_pair(*n, true);
}
```

the error that it keeps giving is:

```
error:   expected a type, got 'btree::node'
error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
At global scope:
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair'
error:   expected a type, got 'btree::node'
```

This seems to be happening on the line:

```
pair <btree<T>::node, bool> btree<T>::addElement (const T& e, btree<T>::node*& n) {
```

I'm calling it the same way in the header, and I don't understand why its saying I'm not giving it the right type. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Your constructor isn't exception safe. You should either avoid saying `new`, or be extremely careful if you say `new` more than once in a constructor.

Comment: @KerrekSB could you explain what you mean please?

Comment: Imagine what happens if the second `new` expression (for `root->lvl`) throws an exception... Let me know if you want some suggestions.

Comment: The necessary information is all covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names , but this can't really be called a duplicate...

Answer (score 7):

You have to say:

```
pair <typename btree<T>::node, bool>
      ^^^^^^^^
```

This is because in the template setting, `btree<T>` is unresolved and `btree<T>::node` is a *dependent name*, which you need to disambiguate.

Comment: See for example http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html , in particular the section "What are dependent names?". See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names

Comment: Right. It's fairly intuitive, though: As long as you don't know what something is (`btree<T>` in this case), all nested names are dependent and must be qualified. It's always good to consider the possibility that `btree<T>` may be a specialization, too.

Answer (score 4):

It is a very common error.

Use `typename` as:

```
pair<typename btree<T>::node, bool> 
     ^^^^^^^^
```

It is because `node` is a dependent type, as it *depends* on the template parameter `T`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `typename` to tell the compiler that dependent name defines a type:

```
template <typename T>
pair <typename btree<T>::node, bool> btree<T>::addElement (const T& e, typename btree<T>::node*& n)
```